# PromQL Query Variable Not Returning Data But Works When Hardcoded

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

I ran into a problem where CPU was showing up higher than 100% and the solution was to divide it by the number of CPU's available.

The following worked on a gauge panel (using  `[ORIGINAL QUERY] / sum(machine_cpu_cores)`):

```
sum(sum by (container_name)( rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[1m] ) ) / count(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="system"}) * 100 / sum(machine_cpu_cores)
```

On a graph, the following will return no data when `[ORIGINAL QUERY] / sum(machine_cpu_cores)`):

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name=~".+"}[$interval])) by (name) * 100 / sum(machine_cpu_cores)
```

However the following will return the expected data when hardcoding the value (`[ORIGINAL QUERY] / 12`):

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name=~".+"}[$interval])) by (name) * 100 / 12
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I expect you have issues with the label sets or more certainly with the cardinality

Display each parts of the expression independently in the Prometheus console and check the labels are the same (ie matching label sets) and you have equivalents number of elements on each side (same cardinality for a metric).

If not, you may have to add [vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) expressions to your query.

Especially one to many matching in the later promql where to would need a `/ group_left sum(machine_cpu_cores)`.